# How to upload images in vue with axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, vuex, vuetify.js

i can't find a way to add post an object with a file "image" in it.

this is how i call the API

```
export default {
  postCourse(course) {
    return apiClient.post('/course', course)
  }
}
```

vuex actions:-

```
createCourse({
      commit
    }, course) {
      CourseService.postCourse(course).then(() => {
        commit('ADD_COURSE', course)
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

inside the component:-

```
methods: {
    createCourse() {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('image', this.media)
      this.$store
        .dispatch('createCourse', { course: this.course, formData })
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(() => console.log('err'))
    },
    handleFileUpload(e) {
      this.media = e
    }
  }
```

and got that error 
POST http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/course 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: `handleFileUpload(e)` sounds like an event handler (e.g., tied to an `input`), where `e` is an event object. If you're trying to access the file data, it would be under [`e.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files), so you should be doing `this.media = e.files`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the `formData` in post request

```
.dispatch('createCourse', { course: this.course, formData })

// Only the course object is passed the formData is not used ?? why ?
CourseService.postCourse(course).then(() => {
    commit('ADD_COURSE', course)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

postCourse(course) {
    // Same case here only the Course is being posted you haven't used the formData ?
    return apiClient.post('/course', course)
}
```

Actually you are posting the course data in the form of json and only the image in the form of `FormData` But this can not be done actually. you can only use `JSON` or `FormData` in one time So, first you need to add all the entries of the `course` object into that `formData` object using `.append` and the pass the `formData` instead of `course`.

just like this

```
.dispatch('createCourse', { course: formData })
```

Comment: i tried to append the two objects into one object like that `let object = { ...this.course, ...formData }
      this.$store
        .dispatch('createCourse', { course: object })` but it gives the same error and it didn't assign the data to course.media

Comment: can you show me the complete course object, i mean the fields (properties) of the course object moreover use formData.append(‘media’, this.media)